# How to create shortcode for elementor custom widget?

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I want to create a shortcode for my custom elementor add-on. Here's what I have done but couldn't get the desired output.

```php
//In functions.php;

    function custom_child_widget() {
        ob_start();
        
        $pluginElementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();

        //using get_name() returned id here,
        $pluginElementor->frontend->get_builder_content( 'custom-child-widget');
        
        return ob_get_clean();

    }
    add_shortcode( 'custom_child_widget_shortcode', 'custom_child_widget' );
```

My Custom_Child_Widget Code goes-

```php
<?php 

class Custom_Child_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom-child-widget';
    }
    
    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Custom Child Widget', 'text-domain' );
    }
    
    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-pencil';
    }
    
    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }
    
    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    
        ?>
       <div>

            <h4>Hello from Child</h4>

       </div>
       
       
       <?php
    }
}
```

I want to show the child widget in the parent widget using the `custom_child_widget_shortcode` shortcode. But failed.
Here's my Custom_Parent_Widget-

```php
<?php

class Custom_Parent_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom-parent-widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Custom Parent Widget', 'industrify-pro' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-pencil';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'parent_content',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Parent Content', 'industrify-pro' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );
        // Add controls for parent widget's settings
        $this->add_control(
            'show_child',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Show Child Widget', 'industrify-pro' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SWITCHER,
                'label_on' => __( 'Show', 'industrify-pro' ),
                'label_off' => __( 'Hide', 'industrify-pro' ),
                'return_value' => 'yes',
                'default' => 'yes',
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'show_child_shortcode',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Child Shortcode', 'industrify-pro' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXTAREA,
                'dynamic' => [
                    'active' => true,
                ],
                'placeholder' => '[gallery id="123" size="medium"]',
                'default'=>''
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }

    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        $show_child = $settings['show_child'];

        $show_shortcode = $this->get_settings_for_display( 'show_child_shortcode' );
        $show_shortcode = do_shortcode( shortcode_unautop( $show_shortcode ) );

       ?>
       <div>

       <h1>Hello from Parent</h1>

        <?php if($show_child){ echo $show_shortcode;} ?>

       </div>
       
       
       <?php

    }
}
```

I could use other shortcode in Custom Parent widget though. What I can do now?